# Cytoscape: Trying to Determine Which of Two Node Types Is More "Central"

Tags: cytoscape

So I have a decently large dataset (4k+ nodes, 16k+ edges), and there are two nodes types (let's call them "A" and "B," combined ~130 nodes) that should be considered the centers of many sub-networks. I'm trying to create a visualization that can illustrate whether A or B is more "central" to these sub-networks. To put it another way, is A or B the more "important" organizing type? If any of this makes any sense at all, I'd appreciate your thoughts. (As a disclaimer, I'm fairly new to the software but pretty comfortable with the fundamentals. Consider me a decently intelligent noob haha)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool included with Cytoscape called Network Analyzer (Tools->Analyze Network).  What you are asking for is a measure of the "centrality" of the nodes.  There are several types of centrality measures that can be used for "importance" depending on what you mean by importance.  Network Analyzer will provide new columns with the main measures of centrality: degree centrality (the extent to which the node is a hub), betweenness centrality (the extent to which paths go through this node) and closeness centrality (the extent to which this node is close to other nodes).  See https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape-tutorials/presentations/intro-cytoscape-2020-ucsf.html#/12 for a brief discussion of some of the common network centrality measures.

-- scooter

Comment: Thanks for your input, Scooter! I have used Network Analyzer but should look more closely at centrality data. I'm also looking through the link you provided. There are a couple things in there that might be helpful.

Comment: And I should add another thanks as well. I just found your clusterMaker2 app, and I think I might have actually generated something close-ish to what I'm looking for. Considering that I was having absolutely no luck with anything else, "close-ish" is pretty darn good. Thanks!